# Can't select .NET Framework 2.0 in Visual Studio Project properties

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, .net-2.0

[I installed .NET Framework Core 2.0 Runtime using this url: https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral  But when I open a Visual Studio (2013) Project I can't select version 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOYxG.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, it's .net code 2.0, so you will not see that in .net framework.

what you need to do, is to find this and than you will be able to develop on .net code framework

[image]